# Retrieving the translated text of a custom exception in Django

Tags: python, django

I am raising a custom exception like that:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class File_Upload_Exception(Exception):
    pass

def myfn():
    raise File_Upload_Exception(_('FILE_TYPE_NOT_ALLOWED'))
```

My question: How do I get the exception message? The below gives the following error: `File_Upload_Exception is not JSON serializable`

```
try:
    myfn()
except File_Upload_Exception as e:
    print(e) #I want to retrieve the message "File type not allowed"
```

Comment: *Gives error*: what error? Include the full traceback in your question.

Comment: @BoarGules Updated my question with the error.

Comment: I say again: *the full traceback*.

Comment: In your own words, when you write `_('FILE_TYPE_NOT_ALLOWED')`, what is the purpose of `_`?

Comment: translation string in Django

Comment: You're problem is that the object returned by the lazy translation function is not a `string` as it might seem. But a `django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>proxy` object, that is not serializable and could not send back as response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments you give as parameters to an `Exception` when you create it are available in the `args` attribute of the object you receive when you `except` an exception.

If you `print()` the exception, Python prints the single parameter by itself with no quotes if only one parameter was provided, or a tuple of the parameters if more than one parameter was given when the Exception object was created.

```
class File_Upload_Exception(Exception):
    pass

def myfn():
    raise File_Upload_Exception('FILE_TYPE_NOT_ALLOWED')

try:
    myfn()
except Exception as ex:
    print('Printed:', ex)
    print(0, ex.args[0])

print()

def myfn2():
    raise File_Upload_Exception('FILE_TYPE_NOT_ALLOWED', 'A', 'B')

try:
    myfn2()
except Exception as ex:
    print('Printed:', ex)
    print(0, ex.args[0])
    print(1, ex.args[1])
    print(2, ex.args[2])
```

Result:

```
Printed: FILE_TYPE_NOT_ALLOWED
0 FILE_TYPE_NOT_ALLOWED

Printed: ('FILE_TYPE_NOT_ALLOWED', 'A', 'B')
0 FILE_TYPE_NOT_ALLOWED
1 A
2 B
```

Comment: Ha!  I thought I'd introduced that typo.  So that's a Django thing, eh?  Well, it gives an error without any Django magic around, so I took it out.  I think all of this would still apply either way.  It would just be a matter of what `_('FILE_TYPE_NOT_ALLOWED')` ends up getting passed as in the `args`.

Comment: guys _() is like a string in django it's translation string. Ignore it

Comment: I think we both did :)

Comment: i don't think `_()` returns a string that's why you get error

Comment: No, it's because '_' isn't defined.  Django must define that as a function.

Comment: `Python’s standard library gettext module installs _() into the global namespace, as an alias for gettext().` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code

Comment: Then why do I get `name '_' not defined`? - It shouldn't matter what it turns the string argument into.  You can pass anything to an Exception constructor as a parameter.

Comment: Nja is correct :) We made it an XY problem. The actual problem is what @nja mentioned but your solution seems a solution to the Y problem and not to X. But anyway, functions should always return that `_` and not normal string.

Comment: But commenting on the question, Nja says that the result of the "lazy translation" is a `django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>proxy` object.  So then we're clearly talking about some Django functionality and not anything in generic Python.  Again, with that code and no extra imports of any kind, I get a `NameError("name '_' is not defined")`

Comment: No.  Apparently it's a valid identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, you simply do like this:

```
def myfn():
    raise File_Upload_Exception('File type not allowed')
```

This is how you can raise a custom `Exception` in pure python. Be sure to pass `string` to the `Exception` `class` as arguments.

Follow official documentation to define custom django `Exception` and error handler [django exceptions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/)

Comment: In Django, we need that  global namespace `_` aka gettext()  as it will not return the translated text